# VS2012 Not able to connect to TFS

Tags: authentication, visual-studio-2012, tfs, http-status-code-307

Suddenly my VS2012 failing to connect to TFS with the following error .
[image]

I have tried removing all entries from Credentials Manager, Restart PC, clearing browser cache, removing my user account frm TFS and adding back again, I also reset the visual studio settings. But no luck. Has any body faced this?

Comment: Looks like a networking error to me. Try invoking the TFS Service URL from a browser and see what you get

Comment: @HamidShahid-thanks for you reply. Yes I can access that URL without any problem.

Comment: Is there some reason that you are using the IP rather than name?

Comment: This the local server in my LAN. All my team members access same way. I also accessed it same way but suddenly it stopped working on my machine.

Comment: @MrHinsh-thank you very much for the pointer. It worked when I used host name.